Interactive debugging in Spyder: calling a function in a debug mode from a debug console
Python 3.11, Spyder 5.5.1. I want to do this: when I debug a function and stop at a breakpoint, I want to call another existing function (that is not called in the code of the original debugged function), but also in the debugging mode, i.e. I want to be able to put breakpoints in the second function, and step through it.
This functionality exists in MATLAB, but I could get it to work in Spyder. I don't event know if it's possible at all.

Set both breakpoints in advance. They both appear in the breakpoints' list.
For the 1st function ran Debug: debugfile("...")). It stopped at the first breakpoint just as it was supposed to.
From the debug console, ran the second function - this time it simply executed the 2nd function, without stopping at the 2nd breakpoint inside it.

This is a similar question
Python: Is it possible to debug with breakpoints across modules in Spyder?
but it was posted over 6 years ago, didn't get any helpful replies. Maybe with newer versions, this functionality exists:

From the debug console, run the second function as:
!debug myfunc2(..)

